# Puppeteer go to a different page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to get my script to go to a new page after successfully logging in, however, it attempts to go to the next page before login is complete.

```
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  page.goto('https://website/login');

  page.once('load', async () => {
    console.log('Page loaded!');
    // Login script here
  });
```

I can't figure out how to go to a new link after logging in though, my original solution was to just do;

```
// go to stats
await page.goto('https://www.website/stats');
```

However, since the page is already defined, this doesn't really wait for anything.

Is it possible to have a callback in the .click() function to go to a new page after?

Comment: const page = await browser.newPage(); will create page, then immediately page.goto("website"); to prevent this just add await page.goto("website") and then await page.once.... you have to add await to wait for the previous process to complete.

Comment: Hey Mic, there's a reason I can't do this. The website has a banner ad that pops up for a newsletter, so the page doesn't really load, and if I add await in front, nothing runs. So initially, I just goto the website and do dialog.dismiss(). Afterwards, everything works well.

Answer (score 12):

The correct way to navigate via a click and wait for page load is to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [page.waitForNavigation()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions), like this:

```
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click('#some-link')
]);
```

However, when you are navigating via [page.goto()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), the above is not necessary, because `page.goto()` waits for page load automatically.

In both cases, you can customize which event it waits for, using the `waitUntil` option, which defaults to the `load` event.

> page.goto(url[, options])
>
> - `url` URL to navigate page to. The url should include scheme, e.g. `https://`.
> - `options` Navigation parameters which might have the following properties:
>
>   - `timeout` Maximum navigation time in milliseconds, defaults to 30 seconds, pass `0` to disable timeout. The default value can be changed by using the page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout) method.
>   - `waitUntil` When to consider navigation succeeded, defaults to `load`. Given an array of event strings, navigation is considered to be successful after all events have been fired. ...

Putting this together, an example of logging in would be:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://website/login');

await page.type('input[type="email"]', 'foo@example.com');
await page.type('input[type="password"]', 'pass1234');
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click('button')
]);

// Now we are on the home page (or wherever we end up after logging in)
```

Some other notes:

- You may need to use [page.waitForSelector()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/1e66d332b8faf6a15803c0ad36178e56d4dadf7b/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) or other forms of waiting if the page `load` event fires before the `input` field is ready.
- You could alternatively submit the login form by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key with the keyboard. This would still require the `Promise.all()` pattern, but means you don't need a selector for the submit button. You may need to `.click()` one of the `input` fields depending on how the page is implemented (e.g. if the page does not use `autofocus`).

Answer (score 0):

Same as the solution below, however if i've understood correctly, you should have the click event first and then wait for navigation.

```
await Promise.all([
page.click('button'),
page.waitForNavigation(),
]);
```